# how to customize the Magento 2, Core API URL

Tags: magento2, api, url, magento2.3.3

**I want to customize the magento 2 core base API URL.**

> For example,

If my magento base url is   http://local.m233ee.com/rest/v1/ . As per my project requirement, i have to change the base URL to http://local.m233ee.com/api/rest/v1/.

eg: change the URL from http://local.m233ee.com/rest/v1/ to http://local.m233ee.com/**api**/rest/v1/.

**Please any support and suggestion will be greatly appreciable.**

Comment: May I ask, why you need to change base API URL ?

Comment: Hi Ajwad, My customer has an mobile App, which uses the magento 1 API . So they don't want to change the API to the Magento 2 format. So the customer is requesting to change the Magento 2 base API url to to Magento 1 format.

Comment: Tell your customer NO

Comment: Magento 1 is near EOL they should be upgrading soon.